# remove duplicates while adding a column in csv file using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, drop-duplicates

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
|innings |     bowler    |
|--------|---------------|                      
|1       |      P Kumar  |
|1       |      P Kumar  |
|1       |      P Kumar  |
|1       |      P Kumar  |
|1       |      Z Khan   |
|1       |      Z Khan   |
|1       |      Z Khan   |
|2       |      AB Dinda |
|2       |      AB Dinda |
|2       |      I Sharma |
```

**Desired Output**

```
|innings |     bowler           |
|--------|----------------------|
|1       |    P Kumar,Z Khan    |
|2       |    AB Dinda,I Sharma |
```

**Code I Applied:**

```
df.groupby(['innings']).bowler.sum().drop_duplicates(subset="bowler",keep='first',inplace=True)
```

but for some reason, it is giving me an error
TypeError: drop_duplicates() got an unexpected keyword argument 'subset'

then i tried without subset:
drop_duplicates("bowler",keep='first', inplace=True)
now i am getting this error
TypeError: drop_duplicates() got multiple values for argument 'keep'

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) first by both columns and then aggregate `join`:

```
df = (df.drop_duplicates(subset=["bowler",'innings'])
        .groupby('innings')
        .bowler.agg(','.join)
        .reset_index())

print (df)
   innings             bowler
0        1     P Kumar,Z Khan
1        2  AB Dinda,I Sharma
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it works!! one little question, i hope you dont mind... what if this data set has one more index 'venue' and i want to sort bowler according to innings as well as venue

Comment: @VanshikaSaini - Do you think change `.bowler` to `['bowler','venue']` ?